# Attempting to change variable values for different securities when same function is run

Tags: python, function, variables, finance

## list below defines securities to be evaluated in below PVGO screen

```
Securities = [ 'AAPL' , 'TSLA' , 'AMZN' ]
for 'AAPL':
    PV = 120
    EPS = 8.31
    r = 0.0519
    K=.86
    D=.88
for 'TSLA':
    PV = 244.73
    EPS = -5
    r = 0.2
    K=.83
    D=.90
for 'AMZN':
    PV = 808.33
    EPS = 4.46
    r = 0.087
    K=.86
    D=.90
```

## the below function defines how the basic screener will evaluate each security

```
def PVGOscreen( ):
      PVGO = PV - EPS/r
      ratio = PVGO/PV
    print (ratio)
    if (ratio < 0.6) :
        print("stable security")
    else:
         print("volatile security")
    if (K < 0.2) and (K > D) :
         print ("Technical Buy")
    elif (K > 0.8) and (K < D) :
        print ("Technical Sell")
    else:
        print ("Not Actionable")

print (PVGOscreen( Securities ))
```

The output I am getting is a below, and is only the expected output for AAPL.

```
0.829059829059829
volatile security
Technical Buy
```

How do I get the output for TSLA and AMZN as well; which is to ask, how do I change the variable value for each security in the list of Securities and have the PVGOscreen output change for each of those securities, instead of only getting AAPL?

Comment: `for 'AAPL':` is not valid Python. Is it some other language?

Comment: `for 'AAPL':` is a SyntaxError, so, are you actually trying to run that as code? The `for` statement is a *loop*. What exactly are you trying to do? Why don't you *pass the values as arguments to the function*?

Comment: `def PVGOscreen( )` doesn't take any arguments but you are passing `Securities` to it. This doesn't make sense. `Securities` is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as several people have mentioned in the comments, the syntax `for 'AAPL':` is not valid Python syntax.

Second, there are much better ways in Python to keep track of the data you have above. Using built-in Python, a nested `dict` object works nicely:

```
securities = ['AAPL', 'TSLA' , 'AMZN']

# Initialize "empty" nested `dict`s to better store financial data
securities_data = {sec: {} for sec in securities}

for sec in securities_data:
    if sec == 'AAPL':
        PV = 120
        EPS = 8.31
        r = 0.0519
        K=.86
        D=.88
    elif sec == 'TSLA':
        PV = 244.73
        EPS = -5
        r = 0.2
        K=.83
        D=.90
    elif sec == 'AMZN':
        PV = 808.33
        EPS = 4.46
        r = 0.087
        K=.86
        D=.90
    else:
        PV = None
        EPS = None
        r = None
        K = None
        D = None

    # Nested dictionary to better keep track of each security's data
    securities_data[sec]['PV'] = PV
    securities_data[sec]['EPS'] = EPS
    securities_data[sec]['r'] = r    
    securities_data[sec]['K'] = K
    securities_data[sec]['D'] = D
```

There are much better ways of doing this work, but I hope this example shows how easily your code can be adapted to make your life a bit easier from a programmer's perspective.

`pandas` is another package that would be very well-suited for this type of problem, but that doesn't ship with base Python.

Third, passing the name of a ticker to your `PVGOscreen` function will make your code more flexible, because you can use the nested dictionary from above to dynamically reference different values for each ticket, e.g. `PV` and `EPS`:

```
def PVGOscreen(sec):
    PV = securities_data[sec]['PV']
    EPS = securities_data[sec]['EPS']
    r = securities_data[sec]['r']

    PVGO = PV - EPS/r
    ratio = PVGO/PV

    print(ratio)

    if ratio < 0.6:
        print("stable security")
    else:
         print("volatile security")

    if K < 0.2 and K > D:
         print("Technical Buy")
    elif K > 0.8 and K < D:
        print("Technical Sell")
    else:
        print("Not Actionable")
```

Testing your function out now:

```
>>> PVGOscreen('AAPL')
-0.33429672447013487
stable security
Technical Sell
```

And if you want the output for each of your tickers, you can try this:

```
>>> for s in securities:
...     print(s)
...     PVGOscreen(s)
... 
AAPL
-0.33429672447013487
stable security
Technical Sell
TSLA
1.1021533935357333
volatile security
Technical Sell
AMZN
0.9365799020003068
volatile security
Technical Sell
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was trying to do. I am entirely new to coding and trying to stay relevant in my profession so thank you experts out there so much for guiding us novices